# NSOpenGL profile version 3_2Core

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl

When I add NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core to the attributes pixelformat variable is nil, but when i remove it pixel format gets allocated. I dont get what is the problem : (

```
GLuint attributes[] = {
        NSOpenGLProfileVersionLegacy,
        NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core,
        NSOpenGLPFAWindow,
        NSOpenGLPFAColorSize, 24,
        NSOpenGLPFAAlphaSize, 8,
        NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated,
        NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
        0
    };
    _pixelformat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc]
                    initWithAttributes:
                    (NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute *) attributes];
    if (_pixelformat == nil){
        NSLog(@"No valid OpenGL pixel format");
        exit(0);
    }
    NSLog(@"Have a valid pixel format");
```

The result is "No valid OpenGL pixel format."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved. need to remove NSOpenGLPFAWindow attribute.

Answer (score 2):

genpfault has the right idea, but neither of those attributes is valid on its own. That is to say, they are not boolean attributes/flags.

You need to match the constant with an appropriate attribute name.

#### Replace this code:

```
GLuint attributes[] = {
  NSOpenGLProfileVersionLegacy,
  NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core,
  [...]
```

#### With this:

```
NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attributes[] = {
  NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile, (NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute)NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core,
  [...]
```

I also took the liberty of correcting your use of typedefs. `NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute` is defined as `uint32_t`, while OpenGL requires `GLuint` be an unsigned integer type ***at least*** 32-bits wide. OpenGL does not forbid `GLuint` from being implemented using something like `uint64_t` in the future.

#### *Use the correct API-defined typedef whenever possible.*

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I've tried that but the result is same : (

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSOpenGLProfileVersionLegacy,
    NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core,
```

Pick *one*.  You can't have a context that is somehow both Core and not-Core at the same time.